# Edit an already exisiting wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

what is the best possible way to edit codes of a Wordpress theme of an existing website? Say for instance I have a menu bar with all the features like About Us, Contact, Objectives. But i want to add one more to it(say Gallery). So how am i supposed to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the content of the website, you don't have to change anything in the theme.

If you are using any GUI for changing just search around. In the wordpress-site you have to go to: My website -> themes (adapt) -> Menu
there you can add or change the entries.

If you have a complete website made with a wordpress-theme on a server you will need some html knowledge to solve this problem. But its not that complex. 
Without the code, noone here can tell you the solution.